# Navigation stack

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am trying the ROS navigation stack for the first time, and I am trying to navigate my mobile robot to a given position. Right now was trying to this using an empty map and a robot that does not have any sensors. is that possible? I've been able to move it by publishing to the cmd_vel topic, so I know that everything from the urdf to the launch files I'm using are currently okay. I was wondering I could I quickly generate an empty map, since it seems to me that's exactly what I'm missing. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Hugo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237534/navigation-stack/) by [Hugo Sardinha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27228/hugo-sardinha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-23**:
You can send velocities command to the cmd_vel topic but without any sensors, you can not doing autonomous navigation with your robot according me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, its possible to move the robot using cmd_vel topic without sensors.
did you do the teleop of turtlesim tutorial?
If you haven't done that tutorial, check out the video below.
https://youtu.be/Qh15Nol5htM

---

Originally posted by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) with karma: 190 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) on 2016-06-20**:
You can create a gazebo world and try to navigate the robot in that.

**Comment by [Hugo Sardinha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27228/hugo-sardinha/) on 2016-06-20**:
Thanks! However, my problem is slightly different (btw, yes I have made the turtlebot tutorials). What I am looking for is to be able to send a goal to my robot a have it navigate there I keep getting the this  "The robot's start position is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail" cont.

**Comment by [Hugo Sardinha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27228/hugo-sardinha/) on 2016-06-20**:
(cont) I have followed the tuturials about it, about to have your map, and costmaps (.http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), but I still get this warning. Obviously, nothing happens

Thanks again!

**Comment by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) on 2016-06-20**:
try the solution provided in the link below..
http://answers.ros.org/question/66399/move_base-start-position-is-off-the-global-costmap/